# Developing a site using both Bootstrap Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mobile

I am a .NET developer and have used Visual Studio most of my career.

I've got my own personal sites.  The problem is, I've never been good at developing a mobile version.

A co-worker suggested I try Bootstrap Studio for mobile.  I've looked at the product and I should be able to adapt to it fairly easily.

What I am wondering going in, do I need to re-develop the desktop version in Bootstrap Studio, or will I be able to merge the two publishes?